# Android - OutOfMemoryError while inflating class com.hultan.formler.ResizableImageView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

I recently modified my app. I added about 30 different fragments (but no more then 2 are used at the same time). I don't know if this drains the ram and cause the problem. Anyhow, The application crashes whenever i open this fragment. I've used log to find out where the problem is. But i don't know **what** the problem is.

**Logcat:**

```
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.hultan.formler.ResizableImageView
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at com.hultan.formler.AccelerationFragment.onCreateView(AccelerationFragment.java:32)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     ... 20 more
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:117)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at com.hultan.formler.ResizableImageView.<init>(ResizableImageView.java:11)
02-18 03:47:35.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     ... 23 more
```

My Fragment

**AccelerationFragment.java:**

```
public class AccelerationFragment extends Fragment {
int color;
Button bAdd;
String yes;

//EDIT HERE
String FILENAME ="acceleration.txt";
//EDIT HERE

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //EDIT HERE
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acceleration, container, false);
    bAdd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    //EDIT HERE
    String read = readfromfile();
    color = Integer.parseInt(read);
    switch (color){
    case 0:
        bAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstylegreen);
        bAdd.setText("Lägg till i mina formler");
        break;
    case 1:
        bAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstylered);
        bAdd.setText("Ta bort från mina formler");
        break;
    }

    bAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(color){
        case 0:
            bAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstylered);
            color=1;
            yes = Integer.toString(color);
            bAdd.setText("Ta bort från mina formler");
            writetofile(yes);
            break;
        case 1:
            bAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstylegreen);
            bAdd.setText("Lägg till i mina formler");
            color=0;
            yes = Integer.toString(color);
            writetofile(yes);
            break;
        }
    }});
    return rootView;
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.app.FragmentManager FragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    FragmentManager.popBackStack();
}
private String readfromfile(){
    String ret ="";
    try {InputStream inputStream = getActivity().openFileInput(FILENAME);
        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);}
            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }}

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        ret="0";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ret="0";}
    return ret;}

public void writetofile(String content){
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try {outputStream = getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();}}
}
```

My xml file

**fragment_acceleration.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <com.hultan.formler.ResizableImageView
        android:src="@drawable/f1a2"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/r2view"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:id="@+id/sView" >

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/acceleration"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    </ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:id="@+id/r2view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstylegreen"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hultan.formler"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.hultan.formler.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The annoying part is that this exact code worked perfectly fine before i added 30 almost identical `fragments` (it's a navigation that leads you to this specific fragment) which are never being used.

Comment: see the error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`... I think you are using `Bitmap`'s of high resolution...

Comment: @GopalRao So the images i use should be smaller?

Comment: Yes... try to use smaller `Bitmap`s or 9-patch images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@GopalRao Solved the problem! My images was apparently far too big. I resized them all to ~40% the size and now it works perfeclty fine!